# Custom Touchpad gesture

Tags: mouse, touchpad, gestures

I work pretty fast so is there any way to add Windows10's 3 fingers swipe in Ubuntu? I use official Dell software in my window10 for gesture control but it is not available for Ubuntu

Comment: What is "Windows10 , 3 fingers swipe"?

Comment: Just like two finger scroll

Comment: You want something like 2-finger scroll? You can do something to achieve it.

Comment: No I have 2 finger scroll but I want 3 finger gesture to minimise all windows at once

Comment: There is Ctrl+Super+D keyboard combination.

Comment: If you need the touchpad gesture, you can set touchegg to that combination.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to minimize all windows, you can use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> keyboard shortcut.

It is possible to set the `touchegg` program to send this shortcut on a 3-finger swipe.

The only problem is that `touchegg` does not work with `libinput`, only with `xorg-synaptics`.

For `libinput` you can try [libinput-gestures](https://github.com/bulletmark/libinput-gestures). It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to setup with "Fusuma". Currently have it installed on Ubuntu 18.10. It's comes with some standard swipes and commands, that can be easily changed. There's an installation article on it here: [Fusuma installation article](https://medium.com/@dgviranmalaka/how-to-enhance-touch-pad-gestures-like-mac-in-ubuntu-18-04-laptop-f5f25d5a0b4f)

**Edit** as @Pilot6 mentioned, libinput-gestures works great too! You just have to create your own config to achieve minimizing all windows with a 3-finger up swipe.